# NSTimer shows UILabel and UIImageView when it stops

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uibutton, uilabel, nstimer

In my app project I want to be able to tap a button, wait 5 seconds, and then a UILabel and UIImageView appear. Here's what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)startTimer
{
    responseBox.placeholder = @"Message Here";
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerStop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    mainInt +=1;
}

- (void)timerStop
{
    if (mainInt == 5)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        titleLabel.hidden = NO;
        messageLabel.hidden = NO;
        messageLabel.text = @"Message";
        image.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Everything's linked correctly, what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainInt` is only incremented when you press the `startTimer` button, so that does you no good in `timerStop`. Also, if you want to increment `mainInt` correctly, use **`mainInt++;`**

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)startTimer
{
    responseBox.placeholder = @"Message Here";
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerStop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    mainInt++;
}

- (void)timerStop
{
    [timer invalidate];
    titleLabel.hidden = NO;
    messageLabel.hidden = NO;
    messageLabel.text = @"Message";
    image.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks got it working now. I corrected the problem myself about an hour ago but your code was probably the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: What’s the point in replacing `+= 1` on the now obsolete `mainInt` with a post-increment? Also, why is the timer still repeating?

Comment: How do you know `mainInt` is not used somewhere else in the class? If the user doesn't want the timer to repeat then they can change that option.